# xml data parsing

Tags: php, xml, arrays, foreach

Sample XML:

```
<liste>
<okul>kod="1" durumid="6" genelid="11702" adi="istanbul lisesi"/>
<puan>genelpuan"2" sosyalpuan="0" matpuan="3"/>
<okul>kod="6" durumid="8" genelid="11345" adi="ankara lisesi"/>
<puan>genelpuan"4" sosyalpuan="5" matpuan="2"/>
</liste>
```

I want the result:

```
genelid-adi-genelpuan-sosyalpuan
sample
11702 - istanbul lisesi - 2 - 0
11345 - ankara lisesi - 4 - 5
```

My code:

```
function getirbilgileri{ 
  $ch = curl("http://www.sample.com");   
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($ch); 
  $tarih = (string)$xml->attributes()->saat; 
  $i = 0; 
  $ids = cols(get('biten'),'genelid'); 
  foreach($xml->Okul as $okul) { 
    $x = getarray($okul->attributes())+compact('tarih'); 
    $puanlar[$i++] = (string)$x['genelid'];  
    if (in_array($x['genelid'],$ids)) continue; 
    insert('biten',parsequery($));
  }

  $i = 0;  
  foreach($xml->puan as $puan) { 
    $x = parsequery($puan->attributes()); 
    $i++; 
    if (in_array($x['genelid'],$ids)) continue; 
    update('biten',$x,"genelid='{$puan[$i-1]}'",1); 
  } 
}
```

The problem is in the line:

```
if (in_array($x['genelid'],$ids)) continue;
```

Because `genelid` is not in the array. Any ideas?

```
foreach($biten as $bitenler) 
{ 
  echo ' 
  <div class="okullar left">'.$bitenler->adi.'</div> // **this is  ok**
  <div class="puanlar fpuan">'.$bitenler->sosyalpuan.'</div>'; // **this is incorrect**
}
```

Comment: Your XML syntax is not valid.

Comment: Is `$ch` actually the returned content, or still a curl handle? Print it out before converting. You should also indent your code.

Comment: xml is only sample
you can see the structure of the XML

Comment: @mrsilver `<puan>genelpuan"2" sosyalpuan="0" matpuan="3"/>` is already a closed tag like this: `<puan>`. You cannot use `>` within a tag. Doug is right here.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml should look like

```
<liste>
<okul kod="1" durumid="6" genelid="11702" adi="istanbul lisesi"/>
<puan genelpuan"2" sosyalpuan="0" matpuan="3"/>
<okul kod="6" durumid="8" genelid="11345" adi="ankara lisesi"/>
<puan genelpuan"4" sosyalpuan="5" matpuan="2"/>
</liste>
```

may be.

Processing what you have as xml if you want to access the contents of the okul and puan nodes is worse than pointless.